# Symfony2 static multilingual pages

Tags: symfony, multilingual

What is the best solution for static, multilingual pages in Symfony2?

I faced the same question not long before, and since I needed a quick fix I did the following:

- Used the JMSTranslationBundle, and the WebUI in it,
- every static page had its own key. ( Something like: `{{'staticContent_about'|trans}}` ),
- Since these pages contained html, but I didn't want the translators to bother with that, I made up some custom tags, and created an extension to translate that.

**Example:**

```
lorem ipsum...
lorem ipsum...
lorem ipsum...
<more>read more<more>
```

That would be transformed thanks to the extension to the following:

```
lorem ipsum...
lorem ipsum...
lorem ipsum...
<a href="some-generated-path">read more<a>
```

Now this solution is pretty hacky, I don't like it, and I think there must be an elegant and simple way of doing this.

To summarise, what I'm looking for is:

- A way to rapidly create static pages,
- It should contain a markup that is simple, so the translators could handle it,
- Sandboxing the static pages, so just the allowed tags could be used,
- Handling of malformed html, if for example: the translator forgot an end tag.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1. Don't make your own markup, you already have twig that is excellent for templating. If you need richtext support in translations, that's a different concept 2. Do you need allowed tags in the entire static page? or in translations? 3. Malformed HTML is not something you should try to fix, unless we're talking about user generated content. As for the static pages creation, there a couple of solutions, including support for multiple languages (if you need examples, I can provide a full answer after you explain points 1-3)

Comment: 1: I don't want to, I just showed how I solved the problem before, and I said I didn't like it. I did it only because I didn't have a better idea. I need a way to translate texts that could contain html, and I need to do it as simple as possible. That's why I replaced certain made-up tags with actual html.

2: Only in the translations.

3: I must ensure that the translation can't break the webpage. Otherwise if the translator screws up something with the tags, the page could break html-wise. I can't just check everything after every translation.

That's all I think, and thanks for the help!

Comment: I have a strong belief that content managers need to understand the power they are given. Now if this user generated content, you are already down a bad path, if this are translators/content managers you can either go the wysiwyg path with something like markdown that has become quite popular in the past years